# Webpack configuration - DLL's optimization

Tags: reactjs, web, webpack, dll, webpack-4

I'm using webpack in my react project.

I'm looking for the best approach about the DLL's configuration,
my latest approach is to split the DLL's to many small files.

the code in my webpack.cofig is:

```
  optimization: {
runtimeChunk: 'single',
splitChunks: {
  chunks: 'all',
  maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
  minSize: 0,
  cacheGroups: {
    vendor: {
      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
      name(module) {
        const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
        return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
      },
    },
  },
},
```

},

The result is a long bundle time.
 This is a good approach or it's better to have bigger DLL's files?